# Usage of focused/focusing/focus

Tags: grammaticality

> In our tutorial, we provide an in depth introduction on Web service
>   composition, **focused/focusing/focus** on the area of formal verification and analysis.

Among focused/focusing/focus, may I know which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

"Focus" is not idiomatic. But any of "focused", "focusing", or "we focus" would be acceptable, depending on what you're trying to say.

> We provide an introduction to web service composition. We focus on the area of...
>
> We provide an introduction to web service composition, focused on the area of...
>
> We will provide an introduction to web service composition, focusing on the area of...

Any of these are perfectly idiomatic; they differ only in the emphasis.

While we're on the subject: "introduction on" is not idiomatic; "introduction to" is better. And "an in depth introduction" is a contradiction. If it's in depth, it's not introductory, and vice versa. Consider changing one or the other. "Thorough introduction" gets the same point across with less awkwardness.

Comment: Thanks! why you are using "will provide" with "focusing", while "provide" with "focused"?

Comment: My sense is that "focused" is talking more about the course as a whole, while "focusing": is talking more about the instance of the course that you will be providing this customer. But these are shades of meaning; it wouldn't be wrong to use either tense with either construction.